# Creating html table from multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, html-table

I was trying to create an html table from a nested for loop array in Javascript. When I try to append the `<tr>` tags to the table they get put in an element called tbody. How can I get the tr tags to be appended in the to the table element rather than the tbody element?

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script src='jq.js'></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <table id='tb'></table>

   </body>
   <script>
       $('#tb').ready(     
        function() {
           console.log('table loaded');

          var ar = Array(2);

           for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
              ar[i]=Array(2);
           }

           ar[0][0]='1';
           ar[1][0]='2';
           ar[0][1]='3';
           ar[1][1]='4';

           console.log('multidimensional array created!');

          for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
              console.log('<tr>');
              $('#tb').append('<tr>');
              for(var k=0;k<2;k++){
                console.log('<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>');
                $('#tb').append('<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>');
              }
              console.log('</tr>');
              $('#tb').append('</tr>');
          }
          //expected:
          //12
          //34
          //actual
          //1 2 3 4
        });   
   </script>
</html>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCy9A/)

Comment: The body content of a table is contained within a `<tbody>` element.  If one doesn't exist, modern browsers will add it.  This is the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: just so you know, you don't need to go to so much trouble initializing the array. Just do this: `ar=[['1','2'],['3','4']];` it's that simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't append content like this to your table, because the browser must redraw the whole DOM, so it's not very efficient.

You should build your table inside a string, then append the whole string to your table, like this :

```
$('#tb').ready(     
    function() {
       console.log('table loaded');

      var ar = Array(2);

       for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
          ar[i]=Array(2);
       }

       ar[0][0]='1';
       ar[1][0]='2';
       ar[0][1]='3';
       ar[1][1]='4';

       console.log('multidimensional array created!');
        //Prepare the outputed string
       var theTable = "";
      for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
          theTable += '<tr>';
          for(var k=0;k<2;k++){             
            theTable += '<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>';
          }
          theTable += '</tr>';
      }
       //Finally appended the whole string to the table
       $('#tb').append(theTable);
      //expected:
      //12
      //34
      //actual
      //1 2 3 4
    });
```

I've made a Jsfiddle for you : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKS4Y/)

Have fun !

Comment: This is good advice, but it won't address his question about `tbody`.

Comment: If you look the code, it say : "//expected: ... //actual". So the "tbody question" is not really the point I think

Comment: The difference in efficiency would be something like 1 dom change vs n^2 dom changes. This is the best solution. From Barmars answer I can see that the browser is automatically going to add whatever I try to append to the table to the tbody element.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. HTML tables are composed of three sections:

- `thead` contains the header rows
- `tbody` contains the data rows. You can have multiple of these if you want to make different groups of rows (e.g. if rows = months, you could have a separate `tbody` for each year).
- `tfoot` contains the footer rows

If you put rows directly within the `table` tag, they're assumed to be part of `tbody`, and the browser creates this element automatically for you. You either have to put all your rows in `tbody` elements, or put them all directly within `table`.

The problem with your code has nothing to do with the `tbody` element. The problem is that you're trying to append `td` elements directly to the table, rather than to the `tr` elements. You're treating `$('#tb').append()` as if it's concatenating HTML text to the document, not inserting entire HTML elements. It should be something like:

```
     for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
          console.log('<tr>');
          var row = $('<tr/>').appendTo('#tb');
          for(var k=0;k<2;k++){
            console.log('<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>'); // Append TD to TR
          }
      }
```

Or you can use CtrlX's answer, where he composes the entire table as a string, then inserts it into the DOM in one step. This is more efficient than building up the table incrementally.

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple tbody elements are allowed by specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <body>
       <table id='tb1'>
           <tbody id='tb'>
           </tbody>

       </table>

   </body>
   <script>
       $('#tb').ready(     
        function() {
           console.log('table loaded');

          var ar = Array(2);

           for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
              ar[i]=Array(2);
           }

           ar[0][0]='1';
           ar[1][0]='2';
           ar[0][1]='3';
           ar[1][1]='4';

           console.log('multidimensional array created!');

          for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){

              $('#tb').append('<tr>');
              for(var k=0;k<2;k++){                
                $('#tb').append('<td>'+ar[k][j]+'</td>');
              }             
              $('#tb').append('</tr>');
          }
          //expected:
          //12
          //34
          //actual
          //1 2 3 4
        });   
   </script>
</html>
```

this is the working code, on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fn4Wz/